# PHP functions within class -- call function within class

Tags: php

I have an interface like this:

```
interface General {
    public function getFile($file);

    public function searchFile($to_search);
}
```

I have a class, like so:

```
class Parent implements General {


    public function getFile($file) {
       $loaded = file($file);
   }

    public function searchFile($to_search) {
    $contents = $this->getFile(); // doesn't work because I need the $file from get_file()!
    // searches file
    // returns found items as collection
    }
}
```

Then in the code, I can do something like....

```
$file = "example.txt";
$in = new Parent();
$in->getFile($file)
$items = $in->searchFile('text to search');
foreach($item as $item) {
    print $item->getStuff();
}
```

All the examples I have seen to reference another function within a class don't take an argument.

How do I reference the $file from getFile($file) so that I can load the file and start searching away? I want to implement it through the interface, so don't bother changing the interface.

Comment: You need to pass in a value for `$file`. Where that value comes from is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the file as a constructor argument, and save its contents as a property.

```
class Parent implements General {
    private $file;
    public function __construct($file) {
        $this->file = file($file);
    }
    public function searchFile($to_search) {
        $contents = $this->file;
        // proceed
    }
}
```

Actually you don't need to do that constructor stuff, just have the `getFile` function save its result in `$this->file`. I just think it makes more sense as a constructor :p

Comment: Totally agree with putting this in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already calling `getFile()` from outside the class, how about loading it as a class property, so you can easily access it in the `searchFile()` method:

```
class Parent implements General {

    protected $loaded;

    public function getFile($file) {
        $this->loaded = file($file);
    }

    public function searchFile($to_search) {
        $contents = $this->loaded;
        // searches file
        // returns found items as collection
    }
}
```